# How to open a UDP port in the Centos 7 firewall, firewalld, using firewall-cmd?

Tags: port, centos-7, udp, firewalld, websocket

Centos 7 server. Trying to open port 3000 for UDP, nodejs `ws` websockets. Any ideas? I'm stuck! I've checked a few other SO posts to no avail. Thx, Keith =)

- If is stop the firewall, the udp unicast works fine
- When I start the firewall, websocket connections are getting refused, and I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- default zone is `public`

Port looks to be enabled here:

```
sh-4.2# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3000/udp 8080/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

From a Mac on the same network:

```
Mac> nc -uz 192.168.1.101 3000
Connecion to 192.168.1.101 port 3000 [udp/hbci] succeeded!
```

- ping to 192.168.1.101 is fine

The only thing I can find that looks fishy is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, fixed it by running:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3000/udp
```

And then restarted the firewall service

```
systemctl restart firewalld
```

Finally restarted my nodjs app and it now worked as expected